# Currency symbol is not displaying in console window

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to print amount with currency symbol in console window:

```
string cultureCode = "hi-IN";//"it-IT";
decimal amount = 123.54M;
CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(cultureCode);    
string strAmout=String.Format(cultureInfo, "{0:C}",amount);

Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

Console.WriteLine(strAmout);
```

Amount is displaying correctly in watch window but not in console window.

Comment: cannot fathom why someone would downvote or vote to close this great question.

Comment: Jon skeet may help me out.

Comment: The used culture is `"हिंदी (भारत)"`, or `"Hindi (India)"`. Just for reference, the string becomes `"₹ 123.54"`, i.e. the [Indian rupee sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_rupee_sign) U+20B9 (₹) followed by a space and the usual ASCII representation of the number. See also [Currency Symbols (Unicode block)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_Symbols_(Unicode_block)).

Answer (score 3):

It is by design.

Console window is displayed using some special font (Lucida Console, Consolas and so on). 
That font not necessary has symbol for your currency, so that symbol can be displayed incorrectly.

**UPDATE**

According to [this link](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/lucida_console/blockview.htm?block=currency_symbols), rupee sign is not supported in `Lucida Console` font.

According to [this link](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20b9/fontsupport.htm), it is supported in `Consolas` font.

Comment: Unknown symbols would be replaced by a placeholder like a question mark (`?`)

Answer (score 3):

The encoding you're using for your output might not include those currency symbols.

try setting the output encoding of your console to one that supports the currency symbol :

```
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
```

Comment: Have a look: OP's question code already contains this string.

Comment: The indian rupee is a tricky one ; but it should be present in both Ascii and Unicode, so this might not be the solution to your problem after all

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20b9/index.htm

Comment: Is there any other encoding available for those symbols?

Comment: Yes, i just posted about that :)

Comment: @TimothyGroote, this is also happening with Italian currency symbol.

Comment: Italy should be the Euro symbol, which is also available in UTF-8
Or if this is a historic set, it should have the Lyra (₤) which should also be present in UTF-8

Comment: @TimothyGroote, Italian is also not working with UTF-8. you can check above code if needed.

Comment: I think Andy has found the solution to your problem.
It is indeed the font, not the encoding causing your problems.